# Space of functions of infinitely many variables with norm different from the uniform one

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider a family of compact metric spaces $(\Omega_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$, and the corresponding product space $\Omega=\prod_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\Omega_t$. I will write its generic element as $\omega=(\omega_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$. Among all functions $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, we may consider those that only depend on *finitely many* values of the parameter $t$, that is,
\begin{equation}
f(\omega)=\tilde{f}(\omega_{t_1},...,\omega_{t_n}).
\end{equation}
By Stone-Weierstrass, the completion of the space of such functions that are continuous, endowed with the usual uniform norm
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_\infty:=\max_{\omega\in\Omega}|f(\omega)|=\max_{\omega_{t_1},...,\omega_{t_n}}\left|\tilde{f}(\omega_{t_1},...,\omega_{t_n})\right|,
\end{equation}
should correspond exactly to the space of all continuous functions on $\Omega$ with the same norm.

I am wondering what happens if, instead, we consider some other norm. For instance, suppose that on $\Omega_t$ a measure $\mu_t$, and with it a natural notion of integration, is defined; as such, each finite product space $\Omega_{t_1}\times...\times\Omega_{t_n}$ carries with itself the corresponding product measure $\mu_{t_1,\dots,t_n}$. We could now endow the functions depending on finitely many coordinates (or a subspace of such functions) with the norm
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_p:=\left(\int\left|\tilde{f}(\omega_{t_1},\dots,\omega_{t_n})\right|^p\;\mathrm{d}\mu_{t_1,\dots,t_n}\right)^{1/p}.
\end{equation}
Could we somehow characterize the closure of this space in a similarly "satisfactory" way as the case of uniform norm (which, formally, would correspond to $p=\infty$)?

I apologize in advance if some of the assumptions above are not precise; examples with "sufficiently simple" choices of $\Omega$ (e.g., $\Omega_t=[0,1]$ and $\mu_t$ Lebesgue for all $t$) would be already much welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each $\mu_t$ is a Radon probability (your seminorm $\|\cdot\|_p$ is ill-defined without some assumption on the total masses of the measures $\mu_t$), one can prove the existence and uniqueness of a Radon probability $\mu$ on $\Omega$ such that

$$\|f\|_p=\left(\int_\Omega|f(\omega)|^p\,d\mu(\omega)\right)^{1/p}$$

for every continuous function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ which depends on only finitely many variables. Hence, the Hausdorff completion for the seminorm $\|\cdot\|_p$ of the space of continuous functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb C$ which depend on only finitely many variables may simply be described as the Banach space $L^p(\mu)$.

---

The existence and uniqueness of such a $\mu$ is essentially a quite ancient result of Daniell. While [his original paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/1967122) only deals with sequences of intervals of the real line, his approach can be easily adapted to arbitrarily large families of general compact Hausdorff spaces. You can find a treatment of this more general setting in Bourbaki's [*Integration*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-59312-3), chap. III, §4, n°6, which also happens to deal with the case of general total masses other than just $1$. You can also check out n°5 for a similar result with complex Radon measures.